# Why are berries always used in singular?

Tags: этимология, множественное-число

I was recently translating a text from German to Russian and came across the following phrase:

```
Salzbrezeln mit Preiselbeeren
```

which means in English

```
Salted pretzels with cranberries
```

I translated it to Russian like this

```
Солёные брецели с брусникой
```

I am a Russian native speaker and realize that I never use berries in the plural form. Some examples:

```
чай с малиной, клубника с сахаром, торт с вишней, пирог с ежевикой
```

I **never** use them like this

```
чай с малинами, клубники с сахаром, торт с вишнями, пирог с ежевиками
```

Would you agree with that? In that case is there any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: related: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/why-%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%ba-is-a-mass-noun-while-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%86-is-not

Comment: BTW,  these are "претцели" (sing.= претцлель)

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev брецель is a correct translation according to the wiki https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Брецель

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422920/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8

Answer (score 3):

Names of small berries are usually used as *collective nouns* in Russian. In cooking, berries are often used in the form of jam, mashed with sugar, so you can also look at that as *[mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)*.

Also, *картошка* and *лук* are always collective: *жареная картошка с луком* – usually it means more than one potato and more than one onion. Names of other vegetables can also be collective: *выращивают свеклу и капусту*.

Names of animals are often collective: *охотились на соболя, зайца, били белку, ловили рыбу*.

On the other hand, when it goes about cherries, it is often plural: *[пирожки с вишнями](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1923&text=lexform&req=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8&endyear=1943&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&docid=L3BsYWNlL3J1c2NvcnBvcmEvdGV4dHMvZmluYWxpemVkL21haW4vc291cmNlL3ByZTE5NTAveHgtMS9zY2h2YXJ0cy9kcmFrb24ueG1sIzAwMjE=), [вареники с вишнями](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1987&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8&endyear=2007&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&docid=L3BsYWNlL3J1c2NvcnBvcmEvdGV4dHMvZmluYWxpemVkL21haW4vc291cmNlL3Bvc3QxOTUwL3ZhZ3IvcG90ZXJpL3J5YXphbm92L29tdXR5NC54bWwjMDAxNQ==)*.

Comment: I think it's more like an uncountable, at least for smaller berries (like blueberry or cranberries. No one will ever count those). By the way it looks like a recent trend: https://tinyurl.com/wwx8lxy (ngram).

Comment: I disagree about cherries. It is much more natural to say `пирожки с вишней`. In fact I don't think I ever heard anyone saying it the way you wrote.

Comment: @user7808407 - What exactly do you disagree with? With the fact that some people _do_ say _пирожки с вишнями_? Or with the fact that if you didn't hear a thing it can still well exist? Even [_пирог с вишнями_](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="пирог+с+вишнями") and [_торт с вишнями_](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="торт+с+вишнями") exist.

Comment: I sort of concur with @user7808407, in the sense that it's relatively _rare_ to hear that; generally, there is nothing special about _вишня_ in this regard. "Торт с вишнями" rather implies that the торт _украшен_ (отдельными) вишнями rather than filled with them (but one can just as well say торт с клубниками). Normally though, one would say пирожки с вишней.

Comment: Instead of downvoting you'd better post your own "correct" answer.

Comment: Despite most _web_ recipes say _вареники с вишней_ (which sounds rather formal, like coming from food _industry_ and reminding of the ill-famed Soviet 'obschepitt' system), there are serious cooking books (e. g. Поварская книга известного кулинара Д. И. Бобринского: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=TkE4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT246&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U19LwGEiLLLj3yifygkKmsbkfe-uA&w=1280 ) describing **вареники с вишнями**. 
Same with черешня/черешни: the _context_ rules. Here's an example from _Pushkin's_ "Выстрел": _Он стоял под пистолетом, выбирая из фуражки спелые **черешни**..._